# Compare $1 with another string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I've spent 2 hours with an `if` statement, that never works like I want:

```
#should return true
if [ "$1" == "355258054414904" ]; then
```

Here is the whole script:

```
#!/bin/bash

param=$1
INPUT=simu_900_imei_user_pass.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT ime not found"; exit 99; }
while read imei email pass 
do
    echo "First Parameter-IMEI: $1"
    if [ "$1" == "355258054414904" ]; then
        echo "GOOD"
    fi
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

This is the output of the script:

```
First Parameter-IMEI: 355258054414904
First Parameter-IMEI: 355258054414904
First Parameter-IMEI: 355258054414904
```

I have seen a lot of pages about the subject, but I can't make it work :(

EDIT: I Join the content of csv for better understanding ! Tx for your help !

```
4790057be1803096,user1,pass1
355258054414904,juju,capp
4790057be1803096,user2,pass2
358854053154579,user3,pass3
```

Comment: How are you running your script? What does `cat -v <<< "$1"` display?

Comment: I'm guessing there's some trailing whitespace in `$1`. What does `echo "First Parameter-IMEI: '$1'"` display?

Comment: I get `GOOD` for each line, so yes, a hidden char is a good bet.

Comment: Also, `==` isn't valid in POSIX test, even though some shells (such as bash) allow it. The correct spelling for the string comparison operator is `=` -- only one character.

Comment: If using bash, `printf '%q\n' "$1"` is another way to see exactly what's actually there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason $1 does not match is because $1 means the first parameter given to the script on the command line, while you want it to match the first field read from the file. That value is in $imei.

You probably meant:

```
if [ "$imei" == "355258054414904" ]; then
    echo "GOOD"
fi
```

Since it is inside the loop where you read input file line by line.

To check content of `$1` use:

```
cat -vet <<< "$1"
```

**UPDATE:** To strip `\r` from `$1` have this at top:

```
param=$(tr -d '\r' <<< "$1")
```

And then use `"$param"` in rest of your script.

Comment: That may be. But why does the existing program not print `GOOD` three times?

Comment: Because `$1` is not equal to `355258054414904`

Comment: That's exactly what the question is about! Why is `"$1"` not equal to `"355258054414904"`? Because it sure looks like it is from the printouts.

Comment: No it is not. Output doesn't and cannot show spaces/control characters before and after `355258054414904`

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's a possible answer. I downvoted because that's not in your answer at all. Using `$1` instead of `$imei` is *not* the culprit.

Comment: Yes I had added a comment about `$1` later.

Comment: When I change $1 for $imei, it works well... ( The final comparison I want to make is [ $imei == $1 ], but $1 is behaving strange...

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro: Can you show output of `cat -vet <<< "$1"` command?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro: And there's your trailing whitespace

Comment: Yes you have `\r` in your `$1`. You need to use **`[[ "$1" == "$imei"* ]]`** condition.

Comment: it's not working... $1 come from other script, but I don't know how to get rid of the last chars...

Comment: How are you calling this script?

Comment: It is the result of imei.sh : sudo /Applications/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo  | tail -1 | awk '{ print $(NF) }'

Comment: see UPDATE for stripping `\r` from `$1`.

Answer (score -1):

To test string equality with [ you want to use a single '=' sign.

Comment: For POSIX conformance, yes. Bash treats `==` the same as `=`, though.